# How to set source for bitmap in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I want to set source for Bitmap from the folder "images". The property of image in this folder is set as

- Build Action : Resource
- Copy to output directory : Do not copy

I can set it correctly in Winform as below,

```
      Bitmap bmp_testing = TestAPP.Properties.Resources.testImg;
```

But on WPF I got error - Invalid parameter.

```
   Bitmap bmp_testing  = new Bitmap("/images/testImg.png");
```

I don't want to use BitmapImage. Please suggest how to set the source for Bitmap in WPF.

Comment: Using Bitmap in a WPF application makes not much sense. It is a WinForms class. What are you going to do with it?

Comment: In that link it is for System.Drawing.Image . I have to set resource for System.Drawing.Bitmap.  Main aim is I'm changing an application from winform to WPF. It have many functions using bitmap as input parameters. So it will be easy if I can set it as Bitmap itself. Rather than changing it to BitmapImage

Comment: Image is the base class of Bitmap, and any Image is usually a Bitmap. Just cast it.

Comment: Besides that, if you want to keep using Bitmap, why not also keep using `Properties.Resources`? Why load a WinForms Bitmap from a WPF Resource File Pack URI?